# bootstrap css in style tag got truncated with angular-cli

Tags: css, angular-cli

I created a new angular project with Webstorm and installed bootstrap with npm.
`npm install bootstrap --save`
and then added the line `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` in the styles key in `.angular-cli.json`. These are the only things I have done and as the picture shows the css got truncated.

I've tried to do some research with no luck. Any help? Could it be that there's a character limitation in style tag?

This is taken from the developer tool.
[image: This is taken from the developer tool]

This is from my .angular-cli.json
[image]

Comment: That's how normally it is shown in the browser(I am using chrome as well) when you expand the style tag in the head tag(where the styles are loaded). Did you find any issues with applying the styles? As long as that's a no that's not an issue.

Comment: Sorry it's getting applied. Thx for the answer